# Can I mix both update and insert in saveAll from JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA and Hibernate as the persistence provider. I have extended my `Repository` interface with `JPARepository`.  I have a list of Entity Bean for a table. Some of them already exist and some of them not.

I want to know what will happen when I call `saveAll` from my service layer and pass this `List`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you look at the `SimpleJpaRepository` which is a common implementation of the `CrudRepository` you can see that it will simply invoke save for each of the elements:

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities) {

    Assert.notNull(entities, "The given Iterable of entities not be null!");

    List<S> result = new ArrayList<S>();

    for (S entity : entities) {
        result.add(save(entity));
    }

    return result;
}
```

The save itself distinguishes itself whether to `persist` or `merge` the given entity:

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

So to answer your question.. yes you can mix both new and existing entities in the passes list.

Comment: One strange issue with this is that saveAll can’t accurately determine whether the entity is new or not. This leads to duplication of records.

Comment: How is that possible, don't we have an `@Id` column that ensures uniqueness, and also acts as an identifier of an entity?

Comment: could this at all be related to maybe the ID generation taking precedence somehow?